# Place Image Outside Block - Tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I am looking for how I could place an image outside a block and control its position. For example, a flow chart outside between two blocks on a page. Another example would be placing several logos around the title on the poster.

There appears to not be a way to do this.

Comment: One can place a tikzpicture anywhere on a page using the [remember picture,overlay] options and anchors like (current page.north).

Comment: I am not familiar with this - would you post your answer with a link to an example or maybe some example code? Thanks!

Comment: There are examples on page 250 of the pgf manual.

Comment: Actual TikZ stuff involved, cannot help you here ;-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, not much to do. A bit of hacking gets results that aren't really satisfying.

```
\documentclass[colspace=25mm, subcolspace=0mm]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usebackgroundstyle{Rays}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
    \column{.32}
\block{Walzing Wombat}{%
    Wombats love the walz, ducks dance dixie
}
\column{.32}
\block[linewidth=0pt,bodyinnersep=0pt,roundedcorners=false,]{}{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image}
}
\column{.32}
\block{lurking lizard}{%
    sassy salamander
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```